# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/net/HostIdentifier

Tags: spring-boot, selenium, selenide, java-17

I would like to have selenide next to spring-boot project. The exact details can be found here, but I am not able to open page from the repository. It fails in the open() method.

What I did:

- Start simple SprigBoot project
- Add Selenide dependency, based on quick start: https://selenide.org/quick-start.html
- Tried to use it, also based on quick start guide
- Pushed source code to github

Please take a look at the repository: https://github.com/OldEngineer1911/demo

Stack:

- Selenide 6.1.1
- SpringBoot 2.6.1
- Java 17
- Using JUnit
- Chrome version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Dependency issue, this case was solved by a few extra rows into build.gradle. Those dependencies align version of selenium across the project, it was exactly those:

```
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.1'
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:4.1.1'
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.1.1'
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:4.1.1'
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:4.1.1'
```